# What is the significance of the certificate in a PDF document signed using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

How can I interpret the left icon in the first signature of a signed PDF document using PDFBox 3? The right icon is displaying correctly in the second signature, but I am unsure about the meaning of the left icon.

Here is a screenshot for reference:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Acrobat 9.0 Adobe had this cheat sheet for the meaning of the symbols in the signature panel:

[image: Acrobat Signature Validation Cheat Sheet]

The exact appearance of those symbols changed a bit over time but the *Certifié* icon can be recognized as

[image: Certified entry of table]

Thus, just like the second signature in your example it is a successfully verified signature. In contrast, though, it is a "certification" (aka "author") signature while the other is an "approval" signature.

PDFBox creates certification signatures as first signatures only if you ask it to. E.g. the signing example code for that contains this code:

```
        // Optional: certify 
        if (accessPermissions == 0)
        {
            SigUtils.setMDPPermission(document, signature, 2);
        }
```

If you don't want a certification signature, drop the `SigUtils.setMDPPermission` call.

Comment: Currently, I am using the PDFBox example to sign documents, which can be found at: https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/tree/3.0.0-alpha3/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature.

What steps should I take to differentiate between an approval signature and a certification signature?

Comment: You create a certification signature if you set MDP permissions to 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Despite using the same code example to create both signatures, the first one being a certification and the second being an approval. I am wondering why the PDFBox code example handles signature requests in this way. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: First of all, a PDF may not have more than one certification signature, and if it has one, it must be the first signature. And the code example, being an example, wants to cover a number of use cases, so it creates both certification and approval signatures.